# Can I install a new Wordpress site inside a sub-directory of an existing Wordpress site?

Tags: directory, installation, ftp

One of my clients has very limited resource. His current Wordpress site is installed at via FTP at `/public_html`:

```
http://example.com/
```

We need to show him a UAT site before replacing the existing site. In the past, we used to create a new site elsewhere and replace an existing site when UAT is passed. This particular client is using a FTP hosting service with specific environment. So we want to play safe and create the UAT site in the same hosting environment.

So, it it possible to install a new separate Wordpress site in a sub-directory of the existing site, i.e.:

```
http://example.com/uat/
```

and hopefully his old site still runs well during the UAT period.

Since he has only FTP and phpMyadmin access, can I just copy a new Wordpress source to `/public_html/uat` and setup there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It won't affect any of the installation.
I have already done this for few sites. Works without issue.